# "ImportError: No module named qgis.core" when importing qgis.core in Python

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo, standalone, importerror

I installed OSGeo4W. I have no other Python version on my computer.
I can `import osgeo`. But when I try to import `qgis.core` I am getting the error:

```
>>> import qgis.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Are you running this in QGIS python console?

Comment: No, I am not. I am running it in the command line. Can I use QGIS only in the QIS python console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that the `qgis.core` module is not in your PYTHONPATH.

See the instructions in the PyQGIS cookbook on how to use the QGIS API from a python script running outside of QGIS:

https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications